# call Activities onCreate or onResume method from a fragment

Tags: android

Scenario :

I have an activity that populates data from sqlite database in a gridview.
I am calling a fragment from this activity by onItemClick of Gridview :

```
FragmentA a = new FragmentA();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.Main, a, "a").addToBackStack("a");
ft.commit();
```

And in that fragment, some changes are made in the contents of the cell of the gridview that was selected.

Then, as I have added it to backstack, pressing back button will remove the fragment, and in onPauseMethod, the changes are made in the database.

```
 @Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    tasksDatabaseOperations.updatenote(id, updated_title, updated_note, updated_date, updated_color, protectredBoolean);
}
```

Now, to make the changes in the gridview of the main activity, adapter.notifyDataSetChanged has to be called which I have called in its onCreate method.

But, as it is a fragment, removing it neither call Activities onCreate nor its onResume method.

Any workaround for this situation?

Comment: Why cant you achieve the same thing in onBackPressed()?

Answer (score 1):

Better way is you should write a callback method using interface to the 
activity from the fragment that you are using so that when this fragment will be 
detached then that method will be called back and do your work as you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options one of which is to use broadcast receiver to signal data update from a fragment to the main activity....another way since you want to signal refresh from from a fragment to the activity is to create a public static method in the activity which can then be called from a fragment